# How to test if unsubscribe was called for subscription in the callback function in Jasmine?

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs

I have this function:

```
getCars() {
        const that = this;
        this.carService.getAll().subscribe(function(cars) {
            that.factoryService.setCars(cars);
            this.unsubscribe(); <-------- how do I test this??
        });
    }
```

The unit test that I have written so far is pretty straight-forward:

```
describe('getCars', () => {
    it('should call getAll() from carService, set cars and unsubscribe from getAll()', () => {      
        spyOn(component['carService'], "getAll").and.callThrough();
        spyOn(component['factoryService'], "setCars");
        component.getCars();
        expect(component['carService'].getAll).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(component['factoryService'].setCars).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
  });
```

But how do I test the `this.unsubscribe()` line? How can I access `this`?

Comment: `component` is `this`

Comment: Nope, it's not an arrow function, so the context is the subscription.

Comment: First of all why do you unsubscribe inside subscription ? Wouldn't it be easier just to use an operator like `take` so you don't handle the `unsubscribe` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks quite messy. I'd recommend you not to call unsubscribe but use a takeUntil. TakeUntil will get listen to a stream that receives one value, as your component gets destroyed.

Just take this library: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@w11k/ngx-componentdestroyed

```
getCars() {
    this.carService.getAll()
        .pipe(
            untilComponentDestroyed(this)
        )
        .subscribe(cars => {
            that.factoryService.setCars(cars);
        });
}
```

Expect from that, you only have to make sure to implement the OnDestroy interface.

Another solution that is even better: Use the observables in your template with the | async pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign Subscription to public variable and test that unsubscribe method was invoked, like:

```
this.subscription = this.carService.getAll().subscribe(cars => {
 this.factoryService.setCars(cars);
 this.subscription.unsubscribe();
});
```

in test

```
expect(component.subscription.unsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to avoid the extra public variable

Comment: ok, you can mock getAll method and return new Subject, for example:
let cars = new Subject();
carService.getAll.and.returnValue(cars);
in test you can use cars.next() twice and check that subscribe was invoked just once